# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1000) (2,)

Tags: python, numpy

I've created a function to define a test statistic, which I want to test in python. It resamples 1000 times from an existing sample (ex. matrix2, which is just a column) and takes the mode of these samples. Basically it bootstraps with the mode to create a sampling distribution of modes for both matrix2 and matrix3. Then, it compares these distributions using the KS test.

```
def newTestStat(matrix2, matrix3):

    num_samples = 1000
    sample_size_2 = len(matrix2)
    
    replications_2 = np.array([np.random.choice(matrix2, sample_size_2, replace=True) for _ in range(num_samples)])

    mode_2 = stats.mode(replications_2, axis=1)
    sampleModes2 = mode_2.mode.flatten().tolist()
    
    sample_size_3 = len(matrix3)
    
    replications_3 = np.array([np.random.choice(matrix3, sample_size_3, replace=True) for _ in range(num_samples)])

    mode_3 = stats.mode(replications_3, axis=1)
    sampleModes3 = mode_3.mode.flatten().tolist()
    
    return ks_2samp(np.array(sampleModes2), np.array(sampleModes3))

dataToUseMatrix= (matrix2,matrix3)
pTest = permutation_test(dataToUseMatrix,newTestStat,n_resamples=1000)
print('exact p-value:',pTest.pvalue)
```

However, I'm currently getting the following error, despite the fact that np.array(sampleModes2) and np.array(sampleModes3) have the same shape (1000,):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

pTest = permutation_test(dataToUseMatrix,newTestStat,n_resamples=1000)
pvalues = compare[alternative](null_distribution, observed)
pvalues_less = less(null_distribution, observed)
cmps = null_distribution <= observed + gamma
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1000) (2,)
```

Does anyone see what the problem could be here?

Comment: Share the whole traceback. If the shapes of the arrays are as you claim then the problem is with one of the other operations. Print out the shape of each array before executing any computations. For whatever operation is causing the shape error, you can broadcast the missing dimension: `array_2_1000 * array_2_ -> array_2_1000 * array_2_[:, None]`.

Comment: We don't know anything about `permutation_test`, so don't know if the error has anything to do with the return of `newTestStat`,  The traceback seems incomplete, or summarized, but apparently two of the 3 variables in `null_distribution <= observed + gamma` don't match - the numpy broadcasting sense.  There isn't enough information to trace the problem back to your input arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `ks_2samp` has a specific `Kstest` return type. If you want a numeric return type, you need to specify:

```py
(ks_2samp(np.array(sampleModes2), np.array(sampleModes3))).statistic
```